# When I create a table using React with a split row in one of the cells I get a warning

Tags: reactjs

I want to build a table using React. I want to split a row into two. I succeed, but I have an error that I cannot solve.
I see the error in CONSOLE and it says

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <tr>.
    at tr
    at SpiltRow (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:428:5)
    at tr
    at tbody
    at table
    at Grandson (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:312:5)
    at div
    at Child (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:147:5)
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34:76
```

I wrote a code that I send from the father and the father to the grandson and the grandson divides the columns

The code is lectureable and I get what I want but the CONSOLE warning
I can't solve

my app is

```
import {useState} from "react"
import Child from "./Child";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [names , setNames] = useState([{Name:"ron",age:"38",adult:"false",locations:[{item:"b33"},{item:"b98"}]},
                                      {Name:"avi",age:"66",adult:"false",locations:[{item:"b55"},{item:"77"}]}])
  const addusers =(user)=>{
    setNames([...names,user])
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">   
      <Child names={names} addusers={addusers}/> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the child is

```
import Grandson from "./Grandson";
import {useState} from "react"

function Child({names ,addusers})
{
    const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({Name:"",age:"",adult:false,locations:[{item1:""},{ietem2:""}]})
    console.log(names)
    return <div> 


        <table>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>location</th>
            <th>adult</th>
        </table>
       

  
        {names.map((nam,i)=>{
            
         return <Grandson nam={nam} key={{i}}/>
         })
          }

    
       first name : <input type ="text" name="Name" onChange={e =>setNewUser({... newUser,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})}/>
       city :       <input type ="text" name="age" onChange={e =>setNewUser({... newUser,[ e.target.name]:e.target.value})}/>
       adult : <input type ="checkbox"  name="adult" onChange={e =>setNewUser({... newUser,[ e.target.name]:e.target.checked})}/>
       <button onClick={()=>addusers(newUser)}> add</button>

    </div>

    

}
export default Child
```

the Grandson is

```
import SpiltRow from "./SpiltRow";
function Grandson({nam })
{
  console.log(nam.locations)
    return (
    <table className="table">
      <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>{nam.Name}</td>
      <td>{nam.age}</td> 
         {
        
             nam.locations.map((location,index)=>{
              
               return <SpiltRow location={location} key={index}/>  
         })
          }
      <td>{(nam.adult).toString()}</td> 
       
        </tr>    
        </tbody>  
        </table>  
)
}
export default Grandson
```

and the SpiltRow is

```
import React from "react"
function SpiltRow({location}){

   return(
       <tr>
      
       <td>{location.item}</td>
       </tr>
   
   )

}
export default SpiltRow
```

I am attaching a picture of what I want to receive without warnings[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use div:

```
import React from "react"
function SpiltRow({location}){

   return(
       <div>{location.item}</div>
   
   )

}
export default SpiltRow
```

Edit:
working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-payne-vfry69

Comment: I want to split the cell lengthwise If I take <tr> it down it splits across

Comment: then, move all your table data in 1 table and use div inside td: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-payne-vfry69

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to
Beginner
You gave me the direction I improved a little from your answer I made it for more than two lines and even if there is not more than one line it will not make a line below
I still think there is a better answer than this but for now this solved my problem
I also sent the length as PROPS
my code is

```
import SpiltRow from "./SpiltRow";
function Grandson({ nam }) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{nam.Name}</td>
      <td>{nam.age}</td>
      <td >
        {nam.locations.map((location, index) => {
          return <SpiltRow location={location} key={index} index={index} len={nam.locations.length}/>;
        })}
      </td>

      <td>{nam.adult.toString()}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
export default Grandson;
```

```
import React from "react"
function SpiltRow({location,index,len}){
    console.log(len)
    console.log(index)

   return(
          <div style={{borderBottom: len > 0 && len>index + 1 ?"1px solid":""}}>{location.item}
          </div>
   )

}
export default SpiltRow
```